# Cant print PID of a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to print the PID of running processes with the "lsof" command.

It seems that i do get the correct PID, but i can't print it with the "echo" command.

Regarding the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

portsArr=(4003 4200)

for port in "${portsArr[@]}"
do

  PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS=$(lsof -ti:"$port")
  if [ -z "$PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS"  ];
  then
    echo "Process was already running on port: $PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS"
  fi

done
```

The output is

> Process was already running on port:

Which means that a PID was identified (the "if" command reached that point plus i did some more echo and i saw that a the PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS was equal to 4003 at that point) , but for some reason wasn't printed in the "echo" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ -z "$PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS"  ];
```

This test only passes if the string is empty. Use `-n` to verify that it's *not* empty.

```
if [ -n "$PID_OF_EXISTING_PROCESS"  ];
```